# Iterating through a vector and deleting contents

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Is this a good or standard practice to code like this to loop through a vector while deleting unwanted elements from it without losing performance. If there is a faster way please suggest it.
This vector is of the form `std::vector<AnimationState*> activeAnimations;`

```
void AnimationPack::removeDeadAnimations()
{
    int counter = 0;
    std::remove_if(activeAnimations.begin(), activeAnimations.end(), 
        [&](AnimationState*& animation) {
            if (animation->isActive())
            {
                counter++;
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        });
    activeAnimations.erase(activeAnimations.end() - counter, activeAnimations.end());
}
```

Edited version

```
void AnimationPack::removeDeadAnimations()
{
    activeAnimations.erase(std::remove_if(activeAnimations.begin(), activeAnimations.end(), 
        [&](AnimationState*& animation) {
            if (animation->isActive())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }),activeAnimations.end());
}
```

Edited Code (As suggested from comments)

```
void AnimationPack::removeDeadAnimations()
{
    activeAnimations.erase(std::remove_if(activeAnimations.begin(), activeAnimations.end(),
        [](AnimationState*& animation) { return animation->isActive(); }), activeAnimations.end());
}
```

Comment: You're very close... Hint: `std::remove_if` returns a value. ;-]

Comment: Ah, nailed it - but now I have a scary code. This is the best-optimized code one can write to the same with the std::vector ?

Comment: `auto it = std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), ...); v.erase(it, v.end());` is pretty well idiomatic – it's hard to answer without knowing what you find scary about it.

Comment: Scary for my teammates - most only just started you know ..... :-)

Comment: There's also [`std::erase_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/vector/erase_if) if your compiler provides the library fundamentals TS implementation.

Comment: propose this code to them and take it as an opportunity to teach them about `remove_if` and whatever else they find confusing, this is very common.

Comment: If your teammates are scared of this then _they_ need to learn C++ better. This code is so common and well-known that it [has its own named idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). ;-] FWIW, there's also [a proposal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/vector/erase_if) to supply a shorthand for this in the standard library.

Comment: You can probably just write `return animation->isActive();`.

Comment: I think I better teach them than changing the code. The code seems neat for me. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Please do not edit the question in a way that invalidates the comments and answers. It destroys important context for future readers. If you have further questions about the "fixed" code, either post another question or append the new code at the end of the question, noting that it's a new iteration.

Comment: Oh ok i am sorry, I will revert the change.

Comment: Note that if `activeAnimations` contains *owning pointers* you must remember to `delete` them yourself. If that's the case, consider using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AnimationState>>` or `std::vector<AnimationState>` instead.

Comment: Memory leaks - I nearly forgot it

Comment: It you are removing elements from the middle of an array very often, `std::vector` might not be the best STL container. Maybe a `std::list` would be better.

Comment: Mostly animations come to the vector after clearing the old animation states so vector suffix for now. I am considering list for the rendering engine. Thak you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is called an [erase-remove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) idiom.

Quote from Wikipedia:

> The *erase–remove idiom* is a common C++ technique to eliminate elements
>   that fulfill a certain criterion from a C++ Standard Library
>   container.
>
> `erase` can be used to delete an element from a collection, but for
>   containers which are based on an array, such as vector, all elements
>   after the deleted element have to be moved forward, to avoid "gaps" in
>   the collection.
>
> The algorithm library provides the `remove` and `remove_if` algorithms
>   for this.
>
> These algorithms do not remove elements from the container, but move
>   all elements that don't fit the remove criteria to the front of the
>   range, keeping the relative order of the elements. This is done in a
>   single pass through the data range.
>
> `remove` returns an iterator pointing to the first of these elements, so
>   they can be deleted using a single call to `erase`.

Answer (score 1):

Removes and delete the element from the vector while iterating through it.

```
 void AnimationPack::removeDeadAnimations()
    {
        activeAnimations.erase(std::remove_if(activeAnimations.begin(), activeAnimations.end(),
            [&](AnimationState*& animation) {
            if (animation->isActive())
                return false;
            else
            {
                delete animation;
                return true;
            }
        }), activeAnimations.end());
    }
```

Comment: You are capturing everything by reference now while in fact you don't need to capture anything in the lambda. You should change `[&]` to `[]`.